# Pure CSS3 / HTML5 Collapsible Menu? Is this possible?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a menu for someone who really really wants a collapsible menu. There are two issues going on. On one hand, sometimes the JS on our wordpress site will refuse to load and we must reload the pages. On this event, no users can use our collapsible menu and it leads to a frustrating experience. On the other hand, I would be open to switching from a jquery menu but I want to know..

Has anyone created a pure css / html collapsible menu that does not utilize jquery in any way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Yes this is certainly possible, and a few quick Google searches should send you in the right direction.  Try to refrain from posting such open-ended questions like "how can X be done".  After you have done some research and created a few test cases that are causing some issues, try coming back and posting the code snippets so as to get the most out of the answers you'll receive here.

Comment: http://www.outofscope.com/css-only-menu-toggle-no-javascript-required/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From a quick google search I found this result

[Collapsible Menu](http://www.thecssninja.com/css/css-tree-menu)

So to answer your question, yes it is possible. However to do some, more complete animations you should require jquery or some other library that does that.

Is this what you were looking for? If not can you provide some example of what you need?